# how to configure Angular 17 builder to work with .glsl files?

Tags: angular, shader

Does anyone have a solution to work in the context of angular 17 with .glsl files (shaders) ?
We used to be able to create a custom webpack builder but now angular uses vite...
What do we do now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [new option just dropped](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/26371) allowing to allow configuring custom loaders with the new application builder

Add a loader option to you config :

```
loader: {
    ".glsl": "text"
}
```

An `glsl` file can then be imported:

```
import contents from './some-file.glsl';
```

Additionally, TypeScript needs to be aware of the module type for the import to prevent type-checking errors during the build. This can be accomplished with an additional type definition file within the application source code (src/types.d.ts, for example) with the following or similar content:

```
declare module "*.glsl" {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}
```

---

<s>I checked with the CLI team to confirm what I thought: It is not possible with builder that ships with the CLI.</s>

Like webpack, users need to create their own builder or use a community builder.

Comment: See my latest update, next weeks release should be able to bring you the desired feature !